# Coloured files and folders - Mavericks and Yosemite

Tags: macos, finder, color

I really liked the colour folders / files you could set in osx 10.8, the ones where the entire folder / file line would be coloured as opposed to the little coloured dot in Mavericks and Yosemite.

Is there an option to turn back on the full row colour fill in either of these versions of OSX ?

Comment: @Zo219 just donwloaded TotalFinder, works great does exactly whats needed and can turn off other features as required. If you add that as an answer to this thread ill mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you kidding. Once Apple takes away, it never comes back. But you can use TotalFinder or, a more elaborate solution, PathFinder, to get the label color for the folder and full row instead of that weeny little tag color dot.

And there are little apps about, such as Colored Folder Creator from '08. that kinda still work ... it doesn't color the whole row, but ....

Answer (score 2):

In the App Store a tool called "Foldery" is available. It doesn't change the color of the label, but the color of the folder icon itself. That does the job for me to separate more important things from the lesser important ones - at least on the Desktop.

This only works for folders and not for documents, of course. But it might fill the void left by Apple's strange decisions partially.

I also would love the get the old label colours back, the little dots are hardly useful and especially hard to see from a distance.